# How do I vertically align two divs at center and keep one div at bottom?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this html:

```
    <!-- Left Navigation Bar -->
    <div class="row" id="columnMenu">

        <!-- Logo -->
        <div class="col-md-2 LogoCol-md-2">
            <div class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="columnMenuTitle">
                <a href="" title="" class="navbar-brand">
                Picture
                <br>
                Imran Name
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Categories -->
        <div class="col-md-2 CategoryCol-md-2">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li>category 1</li>
                <li>category 2</li>
                <li>category 3</li>
                <li>category 4</li>
                <li>category 5</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- About Information -->
        <div class="col-md-2 AboutInfoCol-md-2">
            <div class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="columnMenuAbout">
                My Artify &copy;
                <br>
                All Rights Reserved
                <br>
                Developed by <a>Imran Khan</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want the `LogoCol-md-2` and `CategoryCol-md-2` class divs vertical align middle (perfect middle) and want to keep the `AboutInfoCol-md-2` at bottom.

If you are using Firefox you can see that on a window size of 1080p `AboutInfoCol-md-2` is distorted.

I have the js fiddle.
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dj1betmv/)

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Demo Picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable the use of `vertical-align` you need to set a `line-height` value on the element's parent/container.

To ensure a div remains at the bottom of the window, you need to place it inside a wrapper/container that maintains a height of 100% (The size of the window) and then add the following css to the element you want to stay at the bottom:

```
#about{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
}
```

UPDATE: After seeing Moob's answer (Many Thanks), I was able to make a few changes and get it working nicely in your example. Check this update of Moob's fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/dj1betmv/6/

Seeing as I've updated quite a few times, I thought I'd leave the reference I made on my own if anyone has this question again - [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dj1betmv/5/)

Comment: I don't think this answer is complete enough. I believe there's more code necessary to get this solution to work.

Comment: I'm working on it as we speak. Generally speaking, this answer would be fine, but this guy has chucked a bunch of random CSS in here and the structure needs working on. I'll update when I'm done

Comment: I am checking. and sorry for the the unnecessary code. I am doing this the first time, so I don't know how to handle this the right.

Comment: can you explain me the right way of centering the div. I understand the bottom part.

Comment: Centering a div vertically is quite tempermental, a lot of the time you need to consider the height of the div you're aligning and push the element a percentage from the top.

Comment: okay but you see its not centering vertically at the perfect middle. I was trying that too and having the same problem. its like 40 top and 60 bottom.

Comment: Try changing the `top` percentage value on the element you're centering. Playing with it is the only option really.

Answer (score 1):

Update the CSS declarations for `AboutInfoCol-md-2` to remove the positioning that's inherited from `.col-md-2` and replace with your own:

```
AboutInfoCol-md-2 {
    height: 10%;
    position:absolute; /* position absolutely */
    top:auto; /* reset top */
    bottom:0; /* position at bottom */
    transform: none; /* remove the transform:translateY */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dj1betmv/4/

Comment: I check that too its great same like what  Mr. E  mentioned earlier. now what remains is the centering of the logo and category div. i am trying lets see if i succeed or not.